# Visual Studio 2019 For MAC OS missing some libraries?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac OS.

When I built a solution (which build complete successfully on Windows) got the issue 
[image]

It said that

```
The type or namespace name 'WebAuthenticationSuccessAuditEvent' could not be found...
```

As I know it's apart of System.Web. The lib System.Web is already imported/used in the project.

Are there missing some libs?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WebAuthenticationSuccessAuditEvent is not part of System.Web but par of System.Web.Management. You can take a look to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.management.webauthenticationsuccessauditevent?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Use `using System.Web.Management;` it work well on my Mac.

[image: Example System.Web.Management]

Comment: I already imported/using System.Web.Management too. But it's not help. Any missing? Or is it due to VS2019 problem? I'm not sure if VS2017 work?

Comment: I currently using the last version of vs mac. Have you try the code example given by the documentation ?

Comment: Ah yes, @Maxime. It work well for code example given by the documentation. But it didn't work for my project. May be it included incorrect .net version or something like that? I'm not sure what's the reason. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you try to run your project on windows ? Maybe it’s a problem with the project itself. Is it possible for you recreate and project a copy/past your code ?

Comment: yes. It's already build successfully on Windows. Finally, I manage myself by upgrading the version of .net framework in .csproj file. For example, I change <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion> to <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion> and it works now.